# How to disable the error sound using the terminal?

Tags: sound

It's a kind of plob sound. It's not created by the PC speakers, it goes through normal audio output. It happens for example when I hit autocomplete and there is either no or more then one result. It drives me nuts. I have to use the terminal because I use i3. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

1. From the "Terminal" application's menu go to **Preferences** menu;
2. Select the current terminal *profile*;
3. In the **Text** tab you need to uncheck **Sound / Terminal Bell**